# Today's app extension app group issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ios8-today-widget, ios-app-group

I have get stuck in a code sign issue in today’s extension implementation the whole scenario is as follow :

I am implementing today’s extension in my existing app which is signed with appId `123456789com.mycomapany.myApp`

I have a distribution certification with different app id prefix which I am using in my appid. In simple words the App id Prefix if different the distribution certificate prefix.

I have created a app Group on my developer portal `group.com.mycomapany.myApp`. When I am trying to get the group from developer portal in xcode capabilities it can’t import the group.

1. How can I recreate the distribution certificate with specific App
   prefix?
2. How can I change the app prefix of distribution certificate?
3. What would be the best way to fix the issue?

[image: Distribution identity]

[image: App id with prefix]